# Deleting a row from MySQL in ListView in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm almost done with a trial program where I add, edit and delete stuff from my MySQL database.

But I can't seem to make the delete button to work.

**Here's my code for the Delete Button:**

```
If IDNo = Nothing Then
    MsgBox("Please choose an item to delete.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
Else
    Dim sqlQuery As String = "DELETE FROM tbl_adbms_test WHERE IDNo='" & IDNo & "'"
    Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand

    With sqlCommand
        .CommandText = sqlQuery
        .Connection = sConnection
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With

    MsgBox("Successfully deleted an item.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

    Me.LoadPeople()
End If
```

**The ERROR**

http://stivigan.us.to/images/delete_error.jpg

**And here's the rest of my Main Form.**

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

Public Class frm_main
    Public sConnection As New MySqlConnection
    Public IDNo As Integer

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If sConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        sConnection.ConnectionString = "SERVER = localhost; USERID = root; PASSWORD = loadedro; DATABASE = adbms_test_db"
    End If

    LoadPeople()
End Sub

Public Sub LoadPeople()
    Dim sqlQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_adbms_test"
    Dim sqlAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim TABLE As New DataTable
    Dim i As Integer

    With sqlCommand
        .CommandText = sqlQuery
        .Connection = sConnection
    End With

    With sqlAdapter
        .SelectCommand = sqlCommand
        .Fill(TABLE)
    End With

    list_view_people.Items.Clear()

    For i = 0 To TABLE.Rows.Count - 1
        With list_view_people
            .Items.Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("IDNo"))
            With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("LastName"))
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("FirstName"))
            End With
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btn_save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_add.Click
    frm_add.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub btn_modify_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_modify.Click
    If IDNo = Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Please choose a record to modify.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    Else
        Dim sqlQuery As String = "SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM tbl_adbms_test WHERE IDNo='" & list_view_people.SelectedItems(0).Text & "'"
        Dim sqlAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
        Dim sqlTable As New DataTable

        With sqlCommand
            .CommandText = sqlQuery
            .Connection = sConnection
        End With

        With sqlAdapter
            .SelectCommand = sqlCommand
            .Fill(sqlTable)
        End With

        frm_modify.IDNo = list_view_people.SelectedItems(0).Text
        frm_modify.LastName = sqlTable.Rows(0)("LastName")
        frm_modify.FirstName = sqlTable.Rows(0)("FirstName")
        frm_modify.ShowDialog()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub list_view_people_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles list_view_people.MouseClick
    IDNo = list_view_people.SelectedItems(0).Text
End Sub

Private Sub btn_delete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_delete.Click
    If IDNo = Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Please choose an item to delete.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    Else
        Dim sqlQuery As String = "DELETE FROM tbl_adbms_test WHERE IDNo='" & IDNo & "'"
        Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand

        With sqlCommand
            .CommandText = sqlQuery
            .Connection = sConnection
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With

        MsgBox("Successfully deleted an item.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

        Me.LoadPeople()
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

**Add Form**

```
Public Class frm_add
Public sConnection As New MySqlConnection
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If sConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        sConnection.ConnectionString = "SERVER = localhost; USERID = root; PASSWORD = loadedro; DATABASE = adbms_test_db"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btn_save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_save.Click
    If sConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        sConnection.ConnectionString = "SERVER = localhost; USERID = root; PASSWORD = loadedro; DATABASE = adbms_test_db"
        sConnection.Open()
    End If

    Dim sqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_adbms_test(IDNo,LastName,FirstName) VALUES(NULL,'" & txt_last_name.Text & "','" & txt_first_name.Text & "')"
    Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand

    With sqlCommand
        .CommandText = sqlQuery
        .Connection = sConnection
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With

    MsgBox("The data was saved.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Dispose()
    Close()
    frm_main.LoadPeople()
End Sub
```

End Class

**Edit Form**

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

Public Class frm_modify
    Friend IDNo As Integer
    Friend LastName As String
    Friend FirstName As String

```
Public sConnection As New MySqlConnection
Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    txt_last_name.Text = LastName
    txt_first_name.Text = FirstName
End Sub

Private Sub btn_update_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_update.Click
    If sConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        sConnection.ConnectionString = "SERVER = localhost; USERID = root; PASSWORD = loadedro; DATABASE = adbms_test_db"
        sConnection.Open()
    End If

    Dim sqlQuery As String = "UPDATE tbl_adbms_test SET LastName='" & txt_last_name.Text & "', FirstName='" & txt_first_name.Text & "' WHERE IDNo='" & IDNo & "'"
    Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand

    With sqlCommand
        .CommandText = sqlQuery
        .Connection = sConnection
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With

    MsgBox("Record updated successfully.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Dispose()
    Close()
    frm_main.LoadPeople()
End Sub
```

End Class

**Thanks in advance. :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the connection open before executing the Delete command.
This is a common scenario when you keep a global connection object around in your code.
You gain nothing and there are always situations in which you end with the connection in a wrong state

You could write

```
Dim sqlQuery As String = "DELETE FROM tbl_adbms_test WHERE IDNo=@id"
if sConnection.ConnectionState = ConnectionState.Closed Then
   sConnection.Open
End If 
Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
With sqlCommand
    .CommandText = sqlQuery
    .Connection = sConnection
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", IDNo)
    .ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

but I really suggest to remove your usage of the global connection object and replace it with a local MySqlConnection that will be created just when you use it and closed/destroyed after the usage. This is the intended usage of the [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)

```
Dim sqlQuery As String = "DELETE FROM tbl_adbms_test WHERE IDNo=@id"
Using con = new MySqlConnection(connstring)
Using cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, con)
   con.Open

   With cmd
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", IDNo)
    .ExecuteNonQuery()
   End With
End Using
End Using
```

Notice also that I have removed the string concatenation in your sqlQuery and used a safer parameterized approach (albeit in this scenario and if the ListView is not editable there are no real risk of sql injection)

Comment: Thank you so much. You've been a great help. And I will surely take your advise into consideration. I will get rid of my global connection entirely. Thanks again. :D